# Voice Memos - original timestamp and metadata when saving to external drive

Tags: python, metadata, m4a

I have a number of voice memos recorded on my iPhone that I have transferred to my Windows laptop (Windows 11) to process further and extract information.

If you transfer the particular audio file to a Windows PC, you see the same "downloaded" date/time when you right-click File > Go to Properties > under General tab (both Created & Modified dates :(...).
However, when you Go To the "Details" tab and scroll down through the Property list i.e. Title, Album Artist etc.... up until a section called "Origin", you should find your original audio file date under "Media created".

I would like to be able to write a python script that can access this metadata, however can't seem to figure out how. I know the data is there, as I can see it using the directions above, but how can I access it and store it in a python array? I have tried using the mutagen library, but when I print the keys in the file metadata there isn't one for the creation date. I'm not sure what else to try, but it seems there should be a way to get this information. The memos are .m4a files.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [MediaInfo SDK](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Support/SDK).

Although not mentionned in the [documentation](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Support/SDK/ReadFirst), it provides a python interface, which you will find once you've downloaded the DLL version (look at the `Developers/Source/MediaInfoDLL` folder).